# How to pass a capabilities object to TestNG ITestlistener (Or reference ItestListener methods inside a class)?

Tags: java, selenium, listener, testng, saucelabs

We're currently using Selenium, TestNG and Saucelabs. I'm trying to override the `onTestSuccess` and `onTestFailure` listener methods so that I can set the capability to `true/false` depending on the outcome of the method.

I've tried this a few ways with no success. To briefly summarise:

**MainSauceLabsClass.java**

```
public class MainSauceLabsClass {
    // .....
    public static DesiredCapablities desiredCapabilities;
    // ....
    @BeforeMethod 
    //set a whole range of parameters for Saucelabs here,e.g.:
    desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.iphone();
    desiredCapabilities.setCapabilities("idleTimeout",300);
    // etc...
}
```

**CustomTestListener.java**

```
public class CustomTestListener implements ITestListener {
    // ...
    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
        // I want to pass to saucelabs pass/fail result via "passed" capability. something like 
        // desiredCapabilities.setCapabilities("passed",true);
    }
}
```

Obviously the issue is I can't reference object `desiredCapabilities` in `CustomTestListener.java` as it's set within `MainSauceLabsClass`. My question is what would be the best way of implementing this. either:

- Somehow referencing the same `desiredCapabilities` object inside `CustomTestListener` to call `setCapabilities` method?
- Access `onTestSuccess` within `MainSauceLabsClass` and set it in `@AfterMethod` so can reference `desiredCapabilities` inside the same class?
- Alternative?

Happy to provide more information if required. Appreciate the assistance.

Comment: you've declared your DesiredCapabilities object as public as well as static..so what is stopping you to use that object like "MainSauceLabsClass.desiredCapabilities"? inside the listener class

Answer (score 0):

> Obviously the issue is I can't reference object `desiredCapabilities` in `CustomTestListener.java` as it's set within `MainSauceLabsClass`.

As [Mrunal Gosar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1829500/mrunal-gosar) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449397/how-to-pass-a-capabilities-object-to-testng-itestlistener-or-reference-itestlis#comment58596350_35449397) your `desiredCapabilities` is a `public static` variable and as such you can "reference" it from `CustomTestListener`. e.g.:

```
public class CustomTestListener implements ITestListener {
    // ...
    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
        MainSauceLabsClass.desiredCapabilities.setCapabilities("passed",true);
    }
}
```

However, if `CustomTestListener.onTestSuccess(ITestResult)` is invoked before the `@BeforeMethod` in `MainSauceLabsClass` then you'll get a `NullPointerException` (which is perhaps what you mean by "can't reference... as it's set within `MainSauceLabsClass`").

If what you are trying to do is store data associated with each test then you can use a [`ThreadLocal<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) as each test and its configuration (before/after) methods run in their own thread. You can then set and get values for the current test. e.g.:

**MainSauceLabsClass.java**

```
@Listeners(CustomTestListener.class)
public class MainSauceLabsClass {
    public static final ThreadLocal<DesiredCapabilities> CURRENT_DESIRED_CAPABILITIES =
            new InheritableThreadLocal<>();

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setDesiredCapabilities() {
        DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.iphone();
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("idleTimeout", 300);
        CURRENT_DESIRED_CAPABILITIES.set(desiredCapabilities);
    }
}
```

**CustomTestListener.java**

```
public class CustomTestListener implements ITestListener {
    // ...
    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
        DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities =
                MainSauceLabsClass.CURRENT_DESIRED_CAPABILITIES.get();
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("passed", true);
    }
}
```